# Is the correspondence principle intentionally a physical statement regarding perturbation theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, perturbation-theory, approximations, semiclassical

As a new physics reader I accidentally stumbled across perturbation theory as an idea to relate the modeling tactics I see repeatedly employed in

- Statistical mechanics to approximate molecular motion in a solid disregarding high-order terms of van der Waals interaction
- $\tan, \sin\theta \approx \theta$ in the scope of optics, and pendulums to reduce things to elementary functions
- Kinetic energy in light of special relativity.

However it has now been brought to my attention that these may all also be considered instances of [correspondence principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_principle).

... to draw a formal analogy between physics and mathematics is this the same as

`superposition : addition :: correspondence : approximation`?

Also where can I read more concentrated goodness about the broad spectrum of theoretical antics like this?

Comment: The correspondence principle is, at least in its naive form, is false. Consider the case of a superconductor. It does not matter how large the number of quanta become, it stays superconductive. To the best of my knowledge there is no classical explanation for that phenomenon. On a more fundamental level fermions don't even allow an application of the principle: there can, at most, be two electrons in the same atomic orbit.

Comment: This principle was introduced to me regarding Special relativity. But to try and argue, presumably superconductivity would be approximated classically via Thermal coefficient of resistivity, which could likely be found to converge near absolute zero to predict the existence of that behavior -- even though it is inherently a quantum effect. On your other count, I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around which interaction you're claiming must be approximation.

Comment: Phenomenologically the correspondence principle is trivially false. From a science history perspective there was an article by Heisenberg from around 1927, I believe, in which he suggests that the quantum to classical transition is due to continuous (weak) measurement and he gives a handwaving example in form of a Rydberg atom. In 1929 Mott does an explicit calculation that shows that alpha-ray tracks originate from weak measurement and not from large quantum numbers. In other words, intuitively even the founders understood that there was something more complex going on.

Comment: So then you're arguing that currently there are physical laws that must be the final correct truth then? That doesn't really resonate.

Comment: The facts simply don't agree with any version of the correspondence principle that I am aware of. In science that is enough to discard it.

Comment: It seems there's a language breakdown, since there are multiple instances of items that are called "correspondence principles," wheras my text establishes the definition as a general principle which would be very hard to argue against, that "Any new physical theories must yield the same predictions as the replaced ones." that obviously includes a lot of implicit assumptions that other theories have clearly established ranges of validity. But you've brought up a few examples that you call pathological, but I can explain as a novice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139775/discussion-between-flattermann-and-meltyness).

Comment: The correspondence principle is generally a good guide. There are subtleties, but to call it "trivially false" is far too strong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say there's an indirect link, but the correspondence principle is more "fundamental" whereas perturbation theory is "just" an (important) approximation scheme.

The underlying physical idea is that physics should be *continuous* (actually, *analytic*) if we vary a continuous parameter. This might seem like a strong assumption, but it fits with the general intuition you might have that you shouldn't be able to say whether a parameter is *exactly* zero, or just so close to zero that our experimental uncertainty is too large to tell the difference with zero. (However, there are cases where physics can change discontinuously with a parameter, for example the number of degrees of freedom of a photon changes from 3 to 2 when the mass of the photon is small vs exactly zero).

Strictly speaking we don't ever get to vary a parameter like $\hbar$. But, usually in any specific example, we can define a dimensionless parameter, proportional to $\hbar$, which goes to zero in the classical limit. For example, the difference between the quantized electric field and the classical electric field goes to zero when the number of photons is large; you can think of this as being due to the fact that the [coefficient of variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation) $\sim 1/\sqrt{N}$ (where $N$ is the number of photons) is tending toward zero.

The correspondence principle then concerns *limits* in parameter space.

Perturbation theory involves doing a Taylor expansion in parameter space, and keeping the first few terms. The limit should correspond to the leading order behavior in the Taylor series, if the analyticity assumption is correct.

Comment: I think the electromagnetic field is a singular and maybe even pathological example. Fermionic fields do not have a classical field theory as limit and even with massive bosons the question becomes tenuous: what is the classical field theory of helium atoms supposed to be and does it e.g. explain superfluidity? Is a sufficiently large Bose-Einstein condensate a classical state in any meaningful manner?

Comment: @FlatterMann Yes, for example see https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1986PThPS..86...43W/abstract

Comment: Agreed. Collective excitations can lead to effective field theories. I was thinking primarily about vacuum fields, which is an arbitrary restriction. In the case of quasi-particle case the most simple example that comes to mind are phonons and mechanical/thermal vibrations of solids. But even then not all quantum effects are going away if we are averaging over a large number of quanta. Not even in case of QED, for all I know. The Planck spectrum is independent of photon number, isn't it?

Comment: @FlatterMann There is a classical limit of the Planck spectrum where it reproduces the classical result, the Rayleigh-Jeans spectrum. You can't trust the classical result for all energies, however, because eventually you reach energies so large that $kT\sim \hbar \omega$, so the thermal energy can only excite a few quanta.

Comment: I understand that there is a classical limit which doesn't reproduce the correct spectral result. Large photon number eliminates h_bar for the free field which works for wave optic, diffraction etc. but the resulting theory does not seem to reproduce physics correctly for emission and absorption processes. I will have to look into the phenomenology for superconductivity and superfluidity again to understand where the equivalent lines between mean field and quantum theory are for these phenomena. I am clearly too naive about the transitions.

Comment: Would you say that the $\hbar$ expansion gives us a smooth transition from quantum to classical physics? I think that the transition is discontinuous here. For example, the lowest order WKB approximation is exact for constant potential quantum mechanics, but that's still not classical mechanics. WKB expansion still yields us wavefunctions, so I don't think that the$\hbar \rightarrow 0$ limit of WKB gives us classical physics

Comment: One discontinuity that I can think of is that of the Hilbert space. The Hilbert space of the classical theory in KvN mechanics has simultaneous $|x, p\rangle$ states. WKB approximation, however, is an expansion defined on the Hilbert space of quantum mechanics, which doesn't have simultaneous $x$ and $p$ eigenstates.

Comment: @RyderRude There should be a classical limit where the predictions for observables in quantum mechanics approach those in classical mechanics. This doesn't necessarily mean that every aspect of the formalism for some formulation of quantum mechanics will map in an obvious way to a corresponding element in a particular formulation of classical mechanics. It also doesn't mean that the question of how exactly to take the classical limit can't be subtle.

Comment: @Andrew I agree that the $\hbar \rightarrow 0$ limit gives classical physics in,  say the Moyal bracket formulation. But too many people say that the $\hbar \rightarrow 0$ limit of the Feynman diagram expansion, i.e. just the tree diagrams, gives classical physics. I don't get that because the Feynman diagram expansion is an expansion of the Schrodinger equation wavefunction solution. So the $\hbar \rightarrow 0$ limit cannot be taken to mean classical here. Schrodinger equation only gives classical physics after assuming Gaussian wavefunctions.